# threejs geometry different uv-sets for color (tilable) and normalmap

Tags: three.js, fragment-shader, uv-mapping

i've got a cinema4D created geometry/material with two different uv-sets/meshes for the material. normalmap & lightmap have a different uv set then the tileable color shading.

is there any possibility two pass two different uv sets? as far as i can see, the faceVertexUVs is an array itself, but what would the shader look like?

thanks for an answer!